# Postback only Web Server Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, custom-controls

I have created a Composite Web Server Control which displays Image Thumbnails after a user selects files. This control uses

- DataList ( to show Image Thumbnails)
- RadUploadAsync ( To upload files)

For making the postback on RadUploadAsync I am making a false postback on a label.

```
function OnClientFileUploaded(sender, args) {
    var contentType = args.get_fileInfo().ContentType;
    //alert(contentType);
    __doPostBack('lblSelectImage', 'radListView');
}
```

However when i add this control in a web page, this creates a complete postback of the page. Can someone tell me on how to avoid complete postback and keep it limited to Web Server Control only? Please note that this web server control is present inside

```
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <cc1:ImageControl ID="ImageControl1" runat="server" />
    </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: you need to add triggers to the update panel https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.asyncpostbacktrigger(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: But issue is that OnClientFileUploaded is within a Web Server Control which causes complete postback. i.e. Complete postback happening from within the Custom Control and i need to control it. This control is within a page which has UpdatePanel. As per my knowledge, we can't have a UpdatePanel within a Custom Control.

Comment: @Lidaranis Triggers don't work. Solution which i have found mostly used by people is creating a handler. However i hit one roadblock with Custom Control. [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34348278/http-handler-in-custom-controls-containing-radasyncupload) I finally decided to go with User Control instead of Composite Control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Postbacks can be avoided by creating HTML Handler. For Rad Controls, telerik has given nice sample here.

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/asyncupload/examples/imageuploader/defaultcs.aspx